# What does 1__qem mean?

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit

I reading through the default styling applied to HTML elements for Google Chrome, available [here](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css). I found this:

```
p {
    display: block;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1__qem;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1__qem;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0;
}
```

What does `1__qem` mean?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the WebKit source: [CSSPrimitiveValue.h](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/CSSPrimitiveValue.h?rev=107688#L167)

```cpp
// This value (__qem) is used to handle quirky margins in reflow roots 
// (body, td, and th) like WinIE.  
// The basic idea is that a stylesheet can use the value __qem (for quirky em)
// instead of em.  
// When the quirky value is used, if you're in quirks mode, the margin will  
// collapse away inside a table cell.
```

More information on Quirks Mode: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode

Modern sites should never be in Quirks Mode, so you're safe to assume that it's the same as `em` for all intents and purposes.

Comment: So I was looking in the wrong file. And to be pedantic, this is part of WebKit rather than Chromium.

Comment: Agreed. I didn't use `code` in the first place to avoid that annoying horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. Didn't realize it.

Answer (score 5):

> ### The sheet contains values such as "1__qem".
>
> I don't really have a clue what these mean. The only reference I
> found about this is a post from Bill Brown on the CSS-Discuss list. It
> says:
>
> *I believe qem stands for "quirky em" and is a proprietary
> Webkit syntax used to refer to a margin which can be collapsed when
> the page is in quirks mode.*
>
> According to Tab Atkins, it is some "WebKit magic" :-)

Source: http://www.css-101.org/articles/base-styles-sheet-for-webkit-based-browsers/index.php